# The bottom and the top bar are loading each time I change the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I am using BottomNavigationViewEX and each time I click on one of the buttons of this bar, the whole page is loading , even the bottom and the top bar.

This is the code I am using in each Activity :

```
private void setupBottomNavigationView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.BottomNavViewBar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(HomeActivity.this, bottomNavigationViewEx);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}
```

I am pretty sure that I should setup my Bottom bar in just one activity and not every of them but I am a begginner in Android Studio so I am not sure on how to achieve that.

Thanks for your help, I'll provide as much information as needed.

EDIT 1: Here is activity_popcore.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".popcore">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- Top Bar -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_top_tabs"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Body -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1">



        <include layout="@layout/layout_center_viewpager"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Bottom Bar -->

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my layout_bottom_navigation_view.xml :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/BottomNavViewBar"
        android:background="@drawable/dark_grey_border_top"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">

    </com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need more informations just ask me, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is not here. I believe you should analyse your onResume() block on your Activity/Fragment to identify the issue. and please provide more info.

Comment: I added more informations to the post, i hope you have everything you need ! Thanks for helping me